# Refactoring two code

Tags: java, refactoring

My project need to  parse  two type of text data  into database.

one  format is like this:

```
 <lineNumber>19</lineNumber>
 <begin>
 2013-08-15,2013-08-15,pek001,123456,08654071,CANX,,,,,,011  
 <end>
```

one is like that

```
<lineNumber>27</lineNumber>
 <begin>
 2012-11-02,08683683,pek001,00001234,vvip,1
 <end>
```

the difference of the two text is between the begin and end tag.
so our parsing code come out:
first one is:

```
         inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new   FileInputStream(FileOne),"gbk");  --different place
         br=new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
     lineNumber = 0;
         boolean isDataContent = false;

     while (br.ready()) {
            String  line = br.readLine();
            if(line == null){
                continue;
            }
            if(line.contains("<lineNumber>"))
            {

                try {
                    lineNumber = Integer.parseInt(StringTools.getDigitalInString(line));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    log.error("there is no lineNumber。");
                }
                continue;
            }

            if(line.trim().equals("<begin>"))
            {
                isDataContent = true;
                continue;  
            }

            if(line.trim().equals("<end>"))
            {
                break;    
            }

            if(isDataContent)
            {                  
                 insertFirstToDatabase(line,vo);  --just this is different.
            }


        }
```

second one is :

```
  inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new   FileInputStream(FileTwo),"gbk"); 
   --different place
        br=new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        lineNumber = 0;
        boolean isDataContent = false;

   while (br.ready()) {
            String  line = br.readLine();
            if(line == null){
                continue;
            }
            if(line.contains("<lineNumber>"))
            {

                try {
                    lineNumber = Integer.parseInt( StringTools.getDigitalInString(line));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    log.error("there is no lineNumber");
                }
                continue;
            }

            if(line.trim().equals("<begin>"))
            {
                isDataContent = true;
                continue;  
            }

            if(line.trim().equals("<end>"))
            {
                break;     
            }

            if(isDataContent)
            {

                          insertSecondToDatabase(line,vo);  --only this is different.
            }
        }
```

The two piece of code is in two different service code. How can I refactor this reduplicate code? so that each place Just only call one same function to check the lineNumber.

Answer (score 0):

Have the duplicated code in a class that both the other classes either inherit (inheritance) or include a copy of (composition). Alternatively you could even make it a static method in a utility class.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is identical until a single statement, and it's not shown how you determined which of these sequences of code you should be executing, but just move that branching into the `if (isDataContent)`:

```
// copy/paste from your own, change the if to:
if(isDataContent) {
    if (flagFirst) {
        insertFirstToDatabase(line,vo);  --just this is different.
    } else {
        insertSecondToDatabase(line,vo);  --only this is different.
    }
}
```

Where `flagFirst` is either a boolean variable or a boolean expression to determine which of the inserts should be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'kind' parameter for selecting usded inserting method as following:

```
public void process(int kind) {

    ....

    while (br.ready()) {
        String  line = br.readLine();
        if(line == null){
            continue;
        }
        if(line.contains("<lineNumber>"))
        {

            try {
                lineNumber = Integer.parseInt( StringTools.getDigitalInString(line));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                log.error("there is no lineNumber");
            }
            continue;
        }

        if(line.trim().equals("<begin>"))
        {
            isDataContent = true;
            continue;  
        }

        if(line.trim().equals("<end>"))
        {
            break;     
        }

        if(isDataContent)
        {
            if (kind == 1) {
                insertFirstToDatabase(line,vo);  --just this is different.
            }
            if (kind == 2) {
                insertSecondToDatabase(line,vo);  --only this is different.
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what if there is 10+ kinds of text ?

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. duplicated code? - put in static method in utility class
2. how to differentiate dataContent? - 
   i. this can be determined while parsing the line depending on the order of fields
   (or)
   ii. the callee of the static method can determine the same by sending a flag. But this is not good design. You are placing too much implementation i.e. 2 behaviors in a utility method.
   (or)
   iii. Let the static method parse the XML and return just the line details to the callee. Let the callee handle however it likes. First callee might just want to print, second callee might want to put into db.

So, here it goes,

```
    public static LineDetails parseXML(String filename)
    {

    inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new   FileInputStream(new File(filename)); 

            br=new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        lineNumber = 0;
        boolean isDataContent = false;
        LineDetails lineDetails = new LineDetails();

   while (br.ready()) {
            String  line = br.readLine();
            if(line == null){
                continue;
            }
            if(line.contains("<lineNumber>"))
            {

                try {
                    lineNumber = Integer.parseInt( StringTools.getDigitalInString(line));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    log.error("there is no lineNumber");
                }
                lineDetails.setLineNumber(lineNumber);
                continue;
            }

            if(line.trim().equals("<begin>"))
            {
                isDataContent = true;
                continue;  
            }

            if(line.trim().equals("<end>"))
            {
                break;     
            }

            if(isDataContent)
            {
             // parse line
             lineDetails.setLine(line);
            }
        }
  return lineDetails;
}
```

---

```
public class LineDetails
{
 private int lineNumber=0;
 private String line="";
 // getters setters
}
```

---

```
//First callee
methodA()
{
  LineDetails lineDetails = parseXML(filename);
  if(lineDetails!=null && lineDetails.getLineNumber==19 && lineDetails.getLine()!=null && !lineDetails.getLine.equals(""))
  { 
    insertFirstToDatabase(line); 
  }
}


//Second callee
methodB()
{
  LineDetails lineDetails = parseXML(filename);
  if(lineDetails!=null && lineDetails.getLineNumber==27 && lineDetails.getLine()!=null && !lineDetails.getLine.equals(""))
  { 
    insertSecondToDatabase(line); 
  }
}
```